# Line graph is not showing data from database

Tags: php, mysql, graph, highcharts, linechart

I am trying to draw a line graph using high-charts. I am facing a strange problem that is the contents or data fetching from database are not showing or the graph is not drawing at all.
There is no any **PHP** error as I already checked by error reporting on. Also there is no any error on console.
But when I am accessing my data.php file. It shows the contents like this

```
[{"name":"Month","data":["Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul","Jul"]},

{"name":"Name","data":["Direct Sales","Search Engine Marketing","PPC Advertising","Website Marketing","Blog Marketing","Social Media Marketing","Email Marketing","Online PR","Multimedia Marketing","Mobile Marketing","Display Advertising","Direct Sales","Search Engine Marketing","PPC Advertising","Website Marketing","Blog Marketing","Social Media Marketing","Email Marketing","Online PR","Multimedia Marketing","Mobile Marketing","Display Advertising"]}]
```

Actually this is the content that I want to be shown on graph.
I did not find any solution to this.
Please help me to know that where I am going wrong.
Hope I have explained my issue well!

index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
include './includes/db_connection.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Month Vs Names',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: json
            });
        });

    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

data.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
include './includes/db_connection.php';

//$check = "SELECT month FROM activities";
$sth1 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT month FROM activities");
//print_r($sth1);
 //die($check."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());


$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Month';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth1)) {
    $rows['data'][] = $r['month'];
}

//$check1 = ;
$sth = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT name FROM web_marketing");
//print_r($sth);
 //die($check."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'Name';
while($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $rr['name'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);

echo json_encode($result,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: How your JSON does it looks like ?

Comment: so what exactly are you expecting to see in the chart? If what you have posted is your data, the chart can't do anything with that - you need to send numeric values of some sort. Elaborate on what you want to do with those categorical values, and maybe we can get somewhere with it.

Comment: @SebastianBochan
I am trying to display the data fetching from database on x and y axis, via json array.Now tell, what should and how should i do that ?

Comment: Please answer to points in the jlbriggs' comment

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the format of `json` that set in series object.

```
series: json
```

First, data of Series object would have to be number format *(etc. 0.23 or 6).*

and I didn't understand where you want to set display those contents *(title or tooltip on graph?)*,

Anyway, under the contents will be displayed in chart, if you set the **`name's value` of Series object** or **categories object of xAxis**.

*"Direct Sales","Search Engine Marketing","PPC Advertising","Website Marketing","Blog Marketing","Social Media Marketing","Email Marketing","Online PR","Multimedia Marketing","Mobile Marketing","Display Advertising","Direct Sales","Search Engine Marketing","PPC Advertising","Website Marketing","Blog Marketing","Social Media Marketing","Email Marketing","Online PR","Multimedia Marketing","Mobile Marketing","Display Advertising"*

> I have wrote chart's example below. hope that it works for you.
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/uv7cvfsb/1/
>
> also, maybe this picture will help to understand about the structure of Highchart.
>
> http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8U9LxYsbp1k/UDUYsSJxN_I/AAAAAAAAAtk/SNWsEJUIGu8/s1600/highcharts.png

if you want to ask defferent things, please leave a comment.

Comment: sorry for late reply !. I read out your answer today.
I saw your work on js-fiddle, that's working fine.
But you are displaying data by hard code. See my code. I am trying to fetching data from database through ajax json.
Now tell me , how can i do that ?